# Although the header is correct From: does not change in php mail

Tags: php, email

Hello i am trying to build an email class in which the user can send html mail. The user must be able to set the To:, Cc:, Bcc:, From:. Everything works except from. The From Name changes but the email does not.

The addFrom Function:

```
public function addFrom($from, $name = 'Test Email'){
        $this->_headers .= "From: " . $name ." ". strip_tags($from) . "" . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

In Gmail i see this:

[image]

Even though when i call the addFrom Method i set:

```
$mail->addFrom('dotpass@hotmail.com');
```

I also tried adding the <> around the from in the function but no email show up.

I also print_r my headers:

[image]

How can i set the from to change? I am running this on localhost.

Comment: How are you sending the email? Via sendmail, SMTP, etc etc?

Comment: Maybe the SMTP server that you're using isn't allowing the use of unauthorised addresses. What SMTP server are you using for this?

Comment: i am using the one from xampp. @JamieBicknell i am using xampp SMTP i think to send mail

Comment: If you're using SMTP (ie: using your gmail account instead of sendmail or similar) then it sounds like Gmail is not allowing you to change the from email due to security restrictions, like @Blaatpraat said.

Comment: xampp does not have a SMTP in it's package. Probably you've configured the mail settings in PHP.ini for this, there you can find the SMTP server.

Comment: yes exactly in php.ini and i had to login with my gmail credentials

Comment: There you have the problem: the SMTP server of gmail does not allow the use of other mailadresses than your own gmail address. Otherwise it would be easy (it still is) for you to pretend to be someone else

Comment: well in that case i will have to go with hotmail i guess or another email provider